# Some tips with Go and Gogland

Tags: go, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

Hi all. I'm very new with Go and Gogland. I have a project
[image: Go project in Gogland]

1. I choose "Run kind" as Package - to run not only main file but a project. Why it cannot find main package??
2. How to import util.myprinter package to main.go to use it??

Please, help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the general structure of your Go [workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) seems to be wrong. You need to make it look more like this:

```
D:
|-- go_projects
|    |-- bin
|    |-- pkg
|    |-- src 
|    |    |-- FirstSteps
|    |    |    |-- main.go
|    |    |    +-- util
|    |    |         +-- myprinter.go
|    |    |-- SecondProject
|    |    |-- ThirdProject
...
```

Second your `import` statement seems to be empty, I have no idea how GoLand works but if you want to use whatever is in your `myprinter.go` file, you will need to import the `util` package, assuming that the `myprinter.go` file declares its `package` as `util` at the top.

```
// FirstSteps/main.go
package main

import (
    "FirstSteps/util"
)

func main() {
    util.MyPrinterFunc()
}
```

And of course to be able to use anything from `util` there first must be something...

```
// FirstSteps/util/myprinter.go
package util

func MyPrinterFunc() {
    // do stuff...
}
```

**Edit**: I'm sorry, I didn't actually answer your question initially. You're getting the error `Cannot find package 'main'` because of the wrong workspace setup I already mentioned. The `Package path` tells GoLand where the package you want to run is **relative** to the `$GOPATH/src` directory. So after you've setup your wrokspace correctly, you should set the `Package path` to `FirstSteps` since that package's absolute path will be `$GOPATH/src/FirstSteps`. If, later, you want to run the `util` package you would specify `Package path` as `FirstSteps/util` for GoLand to be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. But in gogland you also need to call "go get gotype" - after that import "FirstSteps/util" works fine. And GOPATH for project in settings must be "d:/go_projects" in this case. It's not so easy to dive in - C++ was easier :)